# Has anyone found a solution for Pandas bad data type inference?

Tags: pandas, apache-spark

I tried Pandas for a POC (proof of concept project) because I thought it would be easier for more of my teammates to adopt (normally I use Scala Spark for my ETL). Pandas mutated about half of my data types (e.g. by adding completely unnecessary decimals to integers & other pointless changes like too many extra decimals on floats which causes all sorts of downstream problems when I included it in a POC pipeline. For example, "1" becomes "1.0" for no reason; this effectively turns in integer to a float (that's a mutation! not good...). On a really narrow dataset this might be fine, but on a wide dataset it becomes a severe problem where I'm constantly having to cast so many column types specifically each time I read in a CSV file. I'm debating whether I should skip even doing research with Pandas & just go straight to Spark, or if there's a simple solution for this (I've never experienced this kind of problem with spark). I also wonder if Koalas might solve any of this (since it's Pandas on Spark and maybe it will use Spark's data inference instead of Pandas data inference).

Comment: Very interesting, for the sake of keeping good and consistent ETL processes, wouldn't you want to declare your data/meta types in the first instance ? what would happen if you had an outlier come into your data later down the line? (also isn't that kind of the point of the T in ETL (: )

Comment: Too many extra decimals on floats? Like you want float32s and the default is float64s?

Comment: Pandas has an issue where if you cast a datatype to String it doesn't work, so I had to cast everything to Object usually to prevent modification. However, in spite of these efforts, when you have a lot of columns, its not practical & eventually issues slip in. One solution might be to extend Pandas & force cast everything to object -- I don't know about the computational complexity implications of that though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you encountered is probably related to the presence of NaN alters integer columns to float ones (see [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html)). There's some progress going on, but still experimental.

Comment: Yes, that's part of the problem. If the integer was ever missing, (if there were NaNs) Pandas would interpret all integers as floats, even though there wasn't a single float.

Comment: @JasonF As NaN is considered to be float, any integer column with NaN will be contaminated. For calculation purposes, this should not be a problem. If you are concerned about presentation, just make sure to format the number when exporting. If you are really annoyed by this feature, try casting the column into the experimental '"Int8/32/64" with cap "I", it will allow co-existence between integer and NaN